# How To Check If a FACEBOOK ID is male or female

Tags: facebook

I was wondering can we check the gender of the facebook users using the facebook ID..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention which SDK you use i assume you use PHP 
below is the php code and i think if you can use any other SDK you can also able to use the 
below code with some necessary changes and yes this code is work perfectly i tested this code before answer here :)

```
<?php
 //get the user gender 
        $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
        $user_gender = $user_profile['gender'];
        echo "Gender: " . $user_gender;
?>
```

You need `user_about_me` permission if user gender is not public and you can also get user friends gender using  `friends_about_me` permission if user friend set this public

below is the my authorization code you need to make some changes in your authorization code use the above code in scope

```
 $auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
        . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page) . ("&scope=email,read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access,publish_actions,user_about_me,fiends_about_me&response_type=token"
```

Comment: Nice question thanks for asking 
when searching for answer of this question its increases my knowledge :)

Comment: Hi,you need permissions "friends_about_me"
get this permission and check again :)

Comment: @JustinBiaber  check the answer again i update this as per your requirements

Comment: I asked about change in this <?php
 //get the user gender 
        $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
        $user_gender = $user_profile['gender'];
        echo "Gender: " . $user_gender;
?>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7377/discussion-between-danish-iqbal-and-justin-biaber)

Comment: Hi,
justin
below is the solution for friends if you have its user_id

$user_profile = $facebook->api($user_friend_id,'GET');
$user_gender = $user_profile['gender'];
echo "Gender: " . $user_gender;

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can, use the Graph API to query a user, here is my object, as you can see, I have a property called gender, I believe this property can be hidden if the user has set it up as such, so never assume this is in the response...

This also requires the target user to have granted your application basic information access.

```
{
  "id": "754124803", 
  "name": "Daniel Phillips", 
  "first_name": "Daniel", 
  "last_name": "Phillips", 
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/daniel.j.p", 
  "username": "daniel.j.p", 
  "gender": "male", 
  "timezone": 0, 
  "locale": "en_GB", 
  "verified": true, 
  "updated_time": "2012-02-04T16:00:42+0000", 
  "type": "user"
}
```

If you simply want to test out this, then use the Graph API Explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Comment: how an i get gender of facebook friends ?